# How to declare a generic operator in Dart strong mode?

Tags: generics, dart

Dart lets me declare generic methods, e.g. `T first<T>(List<T> ts)`. But how can I declare a generic type for methods that are operators, like `operator |`? Is there a syntax for this (and is it documented somewhere)?

Answer (score 3):

Dart operators cannot be generic.

The primary reason is that there is no syntax for providing the type. With a generic method, you can call it as `o.foo<int>(...)` to explicitly pass the type argument. There is no place to put the `<int>` in an operator (no, we do not want to allow `x+<int>42`, that just reads horribly!)

Also, if you think of the type argument as an extra argument, operators are already restricted to a specific number of arguments.
The same problem applies to getters and setters, they can't take extra arguments (practically or syntactically), so they can't be generic.

Comment: I find it weird that the reason for not supporting parametric polymorphism is "the syntax would be awkward". You could imagine a world where the type arguments are inferred at call site. But most importantly I think that I'd rather have an awkward syntax to preserve some backwards compatibility of my pre strong-mode libraries than renaming all my operators into prefix methods.

Comment: Generics as a kind of existential type, rather than a parameter, makes sense in some cases. You will have to rely on inference, and with no way to control it, so you cannot know that you are better off than just assuming `Object`. "The syntax would be awkward" is a very good reason to avoid some things - preferably in an attempt to find a better solution with a better syntax. We don't have that yet.

Comment: Let's put it that way: I agree that "the syntax would be awkward" is a very good reason to avoid some things, and if dart was being designed today it would make sense to avoid allowing the definition of operators for that reason. But dart strong mode doesn't exist in a void: there is code using operators and now that code has been painted into a corner.

About inference: my "proposal" was that if inference fail, you'd have to use the awkward syntax, not fallback to object.

Answer (score 2):

Generic operators are not supported at this time.

Feel free to "thumbs up" this feature request:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30048