# Type inference is dynamic on operator overloading with extension in Dart

Tags: dart, operator-overloading

I try to implement pipe-operator overriding `|`

```
extension Pipe on Object {
  operator |(Function(Object) f) => f(this);
}

typedef Id = A Function<A>(A);
Id id = <A>(A a) => a;

var t1 = id("test");  // String t1
var t2 = "test" | id; // dynamic t2
```

with the generic `Id` function above, on `id("test")` is detected as `String`, but `"test" | id` is `dynamic` which is very problematic.

How can I fix this?

---

**EDIT**

Thankfully, @jamesdlin has answered and suggested:

```
extension Pipe on Object {
  Object operator |(Object Function(Object) f) => f(this);
}
```

the result has improved as

```
var t2 = "test" | id; // Object t2
```

I also tried with generic as follows:

```
extension Pipe<A, B> on A {
  B operator |(B Function(A) f) => f(this);
}
```

I expected it would go better because I thought the generic `A` `B` is more specific and better than `Object` ; however, the result goes as bad as before:

```
var t2 = "test" | id; // dynamic t2
```

Why the generic does not work? Is there any way to make the dart compiler infer it as `string` ?

Comment: The generics do not work because the type parameters to the extension depend only on the *receiver* (`"test"` here). Since that give s no clue to `A` or `B`, those are just instantiated to bounds, and then the method uses those bound types.
The signature of the extension method is not used at all when trying to figure out whether the extension applies, or how its type parameters are bound.

Comment: Thanks again! @lrn Your answer is always very detailed and informative. I really appreciated it.

Comment: @lrn One more thing, please. I found https://github.com/purplenoodlesoop/pure/blob/master/lib/src/composition/pipe.dart and  `extension PipeX<A> on A {B pipe<B>(B Function(A a) f) => f(this);}` is this the best implementation what we can get so far in Dart?

Comment: Yes, most likely it's as good as it gets, when operators cannot be generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator |` extension does not have a declared return type.  Its return type therefore is implicitly `dynamic`.  Also note its callback argument does not specify a return type either, so that also will be assumed to be `dynamic`.

Declare return types:

```dart
extension Pipe on Object {
  Object operator |(Object Function(Object) f) => f(this);
}
```

(Answering your original question about a `NoSuchMethodError`: when you did

```dart
var x = "test" | id;
x | print;
```

`x` has type `dynamic`, but extension methods are *static*; they are compile-time syntactic sugar and will never work on `dynamic` types.  Consequently, `x | print` attempts to call `operator |` on the object that `x` refers to, but that object doesn't actually have an `operator |`.)

Comment: @jamesdin, thanks for your answer! After reading your post, I have tried to implement the extension using generic, but it does not go well. Please read my Edit on my Q, and give me your thought. Appreciated.

Comment: @SmoothTraderKen In your `extension Pipe<A, B> on A` version, it takes two generic type parameters, but only `A` is specified/inferred.  Since `B` is unspecified, it is implicitly `dynamic`.  `Pipe<A, B>` cannot infer `B` from `operator |`; that's backwards.

Comment: BTW, it would be easier if you could use a normal method instead of an operator, and then that method could be generic on `B` ([operators can't be generic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47430985/)).

Comment: Thanks again, actually, I found https://github.com/purplenoodlesoop/pure/blob/master/lib/src/composition/pipe.dart  ... `extension PipeX<A> on A { B pipe<B>(B Function(A a) f) => f(this);}` So, this normal method implementation cannot be translated to operator overriding??

Comment: @SmoothTraderKen As I said, operators can't be generic, so no, I don't think there's any way to do what you want with operators (at least not if you want more specific types).

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your answer and comments and URL for the pointer.